# knockout data-text binding with limited character in mvc4

Tags: knockout.js

I have to do the knockout data-text binding. I want to show  with limited character in view. I tried, but it doesn't work. Here  I attached my code. can any one please check my code and help ???

**this my code**

```
<span data-bind="text: (Description.length > 10 ? Description().substring(0, 10) + '...' : Description)"></span>
```

Comment: duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26421749/knockout-data-text-binding-with-limited-character.

Comment: That question does not exist... 404 not found

Comment: The dupe question has been deleted.

Comment: It's a deleted question (now), 10K users can see it. It's an exact duplicate....

Comment: In any case, if you invoke `Description` as a function in the second `?:` argument, you should probably [do this as well in the first](http://jsfiddle.net/zs65hewj/).

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the duplicate answer, but this will work, you're missing the **parenthesis** from Description where you check the length. `Description().length`

```
<span data-bind="text: (Description().length > 10 ? Description().substring(0, 10) + '...' : Description)"></span>
```

see the [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zht3ejnw/2/)